# Get Function Into PS1 (Zsh)?

Tags: zsh, prompt

This works in `bash` (`parse_git_branch` is a defined function)

```
export PS1="\$(parse_git_branch)"
```

But I cannot figure out the equivalent in `zsh`.

**Note:** If I do

```
PROMPT="$(parse_git_branch)"
```

It seems to work, but in fact it's running the command when I set the prompt, which is not the point.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have to include

```
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
```

in your `.zshrc`, `man zshall` explains it in the **PROMPT EXPANSION** section:

> If the PROMPT_SUBST option is set, the prompt string is first subjected
>   to parameter expansion, command substitution and arithmetic expansion.

Answer (score 19):

Actually your problem was not just setting `PROMPT_SUBST`: you use double quotes in your script forcing the evaluation of the function when you set the `PROMPT` variables. You only want evaluation when the prompt is computed that is you must use single quotes.

Answer (score 7):

As akira says, you have to use prompt subst. This is my early code (still working on it):

```
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
PROMPT='$(parse_git_branch)'
```

or better

```
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
PROMPT='[$PR_MAGENTA%n$PR_NO_COLOR@$PR_GREEN%U%m%u$PR_NO_COLOR:$PR_RED%2c$PR_NO_COLOR]$(parse_git_branch) %(!.#.$)'
```