# How to put unread mail messages in shell prompt

Tags: macos, email, shell, zsh, apple-mail

I am using OS X and I want to know if there are any unread messages in my Mail.app?
I want to put that number in my shell prompt.

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, set your prompt to perform substitutions as explained here: [Get Function Into PS1 (Zsh)?](https://superuser.com/questions/142099/get-function-into-ps1-zsh)
Just append the following in your `.zshrc` file.

```
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
```

Then, find an AppleScript that counts your unread mail, for example [this one from Geeklets by Matt Swain](http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/geeklets/system/unread-email-count/). Download [the `.scpt` file](http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/geeklets/modules/upload/attachments/mail_count.scpt) and place it somewhere, e.g. `~/Scripts/mail_count.scpt`.

Note that Mail.app needs to be running for all of this to work. In your `.zshrc`, create a function that calls the AppleScript:

```
function mail_count {
  osascript ~/Scripts/mail_count.scpt
}
```

Finally, redefine your prompt based on the new function. The following would be the most basic approach – but feel free to add [your own variables](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/workshops/zsh/prompt/escapes.html) as needed:

```
PROMPT='$(mail_count) '
```

If you don't want to mess with your prompt or use one of the oh-my-zsh styles, or even the `promptinit` module, you could also just use the `precmd()` function, in which you define anything that should be  run before another command is executed. In that case, you wouldn't need the `PROMPT_SUBST` option.

```
precmd() {
  mail_count
}
```

Whichever method you use, your unread mail count will be output in plain text. If you want to change the messages, take a look at the source of the `.scpt` file and modify it accordingly.

[image]

Comment: This is O(n) where n is number of messages in my inbox, right?

I have too many messages. Wouldn't it be too slow?

Comment: Yes, correct. It could be a little slow. I just tested it with dummy values, obviously, on a rather fast machine – near instantaneous. Your mileage may vary. You might be able to count differently – using `unread count of every mailbox` as [explained here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/applescript-users/2009/May/msg00117.html).

Comment: I posted the better script as an answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 2):

```
set output_string to ""
tell application "Mail"
    set Unread_Count to unread count of inbox
    if Unread_Count is 0 then
        set output_string to ""
    else if Unread_Count is 1 then
        set output_string to "1 message"
    else
        set output_string to ("" & (get Unread_Count) & " messages")
    end if
end tell
return output_string
```

I found this most efficient.

Comment: Cool. If you only want the inbox and don't use nested folders, that's definitely a more efficient solution.